# How to iteratively define coordinates in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, coordinates

I'm attempting to iteratively define a coordinate system in `TikZ`. Essentially, I'd want to replicate the following using a `\foreach` command:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (0,1);
\coordinate (A3) at (0,2);
\coordinate (B1) at (1,0);
\coordinate (B2) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B3) at (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there any way that I can create something like the following?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2}
    {
         [define A coordinates];
         [define B coordinates];
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `(A\i)`

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,1,2} {
    \coordinate(A\i) at (0, \i);
    \coordinate(B\i) at (1, \i);
  }

  \foreach \i in {0,1,2} {
    \fill[red] (A\i) circle (0.2);
    \fill[blue] (B\i) circle (0.2);
    \draw[orange] (A\i) -- (B\i);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I really should have tried this before posting; it seems so obvious now.

Comment: Do not work if you want `A1,...,B3` (as in the OP) and not `A0,...,B2`. See [@percusse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430892) how to do it.

Answer (score 8):

You can cut down some code via the `count` key but it is only worth if you have a lot of them. What you have is basically better in terms of readability in my opinion.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 0] in {A,B}{
  \foreach\y[count=\yi] in{0,1,2}{
    \coordinate (\x\yi) at (\xi,\y);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This looks like a code golfing `\path foreach[count=\n]~in{0,1,2}{(0,~)coordinate(A\n)(,~)coordinate(B\n)};` ;)